# How do I get the photos of a user in Instagram using npm package "Instagram-private-api"?

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm currently using [this npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/instagram-private-api/v/0.10.1) to interact with Instagram.

In its documentation, it doesn't say how you are meant to get the photos a user on Instagram has uploaded.

I searched far and wide on google, finding its github repo, and found that this piece of code should work:

```
const id = await ig.user.getIdByUsername("xxx");
const feed = ig.feed.user(id);
const list = await feed.items();
```

However, that is on the newer version of the node package, which no longer supports some of the old features I am currently using.

I modified the code, turning it into

```
//Declare instagram API variables
var Client = require('instagram-private-api').V1;
var accdetails = require('./configs/account.json');

//Initialize Instagram API
var device = new Client.Device(accdetails["insta_username"]);
var storage = new Client.CookieFileStorage('./cookies/' + accdetails["insta_username"] + '.json');
//Login to Instagram
Client.Session.create(device, storage, accdetails["insta_username"], accdetails["insta_password"]).then(async function(session) {
    const id = await Client.user.getIdByUsername("xxx");
    const feed = Client.feed.user(id);
    const list = await feed.items();
        console.log(list);
});
```

However, it returns Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'getIdByUsername' of undefined instead.

So my question is, how do I achieve the same thing, but on version 0.10.1 of the node package?

Comment: You should ask the maintainer. The chances of someone knowing here are slim.